# ImageSpan makes extra space between textlines

Tags: java, android, spannablestring, imagespan

While trying to give `ImageSpan` to front of `textview` I am getting extra space between the lines on tablet e.g. Nexus 7

[image]

But on Nexus5x it's ok

[image]

```
 public void setTitleWithItemCount(String name, int itemCount, @StringRes int singularResID, @StringRes int pluralRedID) {
        final String itemNoun = itemCount == 1 ? getResources().getString(singularResID) : getResources().getString(pluralRedID);
        final String title = getResources().getString(R.string.work_summary_tile_title,
                                                      " " + name,
                                                      itemCount,
                                                      itemNoun);
        final SpannableStringBuilder workItemTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(title);

        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(actionImage);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        workItemTxt.setSpan(span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        workItemTxt.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.WorkItemTitleText),
                            1,
                            name.length(),
                            Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        workItemTxt.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(getContext(), R.style.WorkItemSubTitleText),
                            name.length(),
                            title.length() + 1,
                            Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        titleView.setText(workItemTxt);
    }
```

**xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="-20dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image_container"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/progress_title"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:lines="3"
    android:maxLines="3"
    android:textAppearance="@style/WorkItemTitleText"
    tools:text="@string/lorem_ispum_short"/>
```

How can I solve this issue?Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try one library is used to set value it same all the device. no issue for mange all the device ..

Add below dependency into app level gradle file ..

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

then after giving value in this way in all controls..

```
     android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_75sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_75sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_15sdp"
```